# I am not able to retrive OneToOneField data from backend Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

i can get data from backend from User e.g user.id but when i want to get data from OneToOneField e.g user.checkAdmin.isAdmin  its not displaying any data in html page

views.py

```
def registerView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        isAdminForm = checkAdminForm(request.POST) #
        if form.is_valid() and isAdminForm.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            isAdminFormObject = isAdminForm.save(commit=False)
            isAdminFormObject.user = user
            isAdminFormObject.save()
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        isAdminForm = checkAdminForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html',{'form':form,'isAdminForm':isAdminForm})
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import checkAdmin


class checkAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model =  checkAdmin
        fields = ['isAdmin']
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class checkAdmin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}
   <h1>Welcome, {{ user.id }}</h1>
   <h1>check?,{{ user.checkAdmin.isAdmin }}</h1>


    <button>Mark Attendance</button>  <button>Mark Leave</button>  <button>View Attance</button>
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **checkadmin** instead of **checkAdmin**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
   <h1>Welcome, {{ user.id }}</h1>
   <h1>check?,{{ user.checkadmin.isAdmin }}</h1>
   <button>Mark Attendance</button>  <button>Mark Leave</button>  <button>View Attance</button>
    <a href="">Logout</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir.. it worked.. kindly tell me why this in lowercase worked instead of that i written in model.py class name as checkAdmin?

Comment: Classes name are converted to lowercase in Django template variables. I don't know exactly why. Please mark the answer as accepted